# Format or pass string from PHP (javascript) to jquery timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending a dateText first to PHP and then to MySQL. Upon response from my SQL server, I want to echo the string to javascript (jquery).

So far all works, but I cannot pass the string from callback from $.post to disabledTime without removing the `''` from the beginning and end of the string.
Everything else works perfect.  Any ideas?

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var selected = dateText;
    $.post('plik.php?mdate='+selected, function(queryResult){ var disabledTime = queryResult;

                                                              $('#timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disabledTime);
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In plik.php, you can pass back the data as json, which makes it really easy to use in jQuery. I don't know what the actual value is, so I used the placeholder "THE VALUE OF DISABLED TIME".

```
echo json_encode( array(
    'disabledTime' => 'THE VALUE OF DISABLED TIME'
));
```

Then in JS, use the json. I converted this to a jQuery get request, based on what you were showing in your code:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var selected = dateText;
    $.get('plik.php', {'mdate':selected}, function(data){ 
        $('#timepicker').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', data.disabledTime);
    }, 'json');
}
```